# Answering "Do you like something/doing something" questions

Tags: grammar

I am having a big trouble about answering questions like "Do you like swimming ?". Though, this is a very simple language, I've always thought that it is correct to answer by saying "Yes, I like swimming because..." or "No, I don't like it because...". But today, an IELTS tutor strictly underlined that I will lose mark, he said that it is grammatically incorrect to start with "Yes, I like..." Please note that the tutor doesn't claim it is not just inappropriate for IELTS, it is incorrect in general he says. I asked a native, who is also a teacher, there is a controversion as the second teacher said that it is grammaticaly correct to answer by saying "Yes, I like..." Please answer if it is grammaticaly correct or incorrect to answer a "Do you like sth/doing sth" question by beginning with "Yes, I like" in informal speaking. I'm not asking specifically for IELTS. What is the accepted view for it, what is the rule, is it really grammaticaly incorrect ? Thank you.

Comment: You know, you don't need a space before a question mark.

Answer (score 1):

Your tutor could argue that the usage is a comma splice, where "yes/no" is the answer to the question and "I like/dislike..." elaborates on this answer in a separate clause which should be separated from the first word by a semicolon.

> Yes; I like swimming because...

But I'd be surprised to see any native speaker use a semicolon in this scenario. The use of a comma here is idiomatic and in my view your tutor is wrong to deduct marks for it.

Comment: Thank you but what I'm asking is completely about spoken English, especially informal speaking. I don't think the tutor mentioned the punctiation. He was a hundred percent sure it is grammaticaly incorrect to say "Yes I like swimming becausem..." just because I started with "Yes  I like" and she underlined that it should be "Yes, I do" but not "Yes, I like." which doesn't make any sense to mem

Comment: In informal speech, there's even less reason to object to it.

Comment: Yes, but you know IELTS is a test to asses English level, however yes many resources say that making some mistakes are acceptable. Well, the tutor was obsessly correcting me, it was disgusting and I want to be sure if this is really GRAMMATICALLY INCORRECT to say "Yes, I like swimming because...", there was no problem about the rest of the sentence, he corrected the first part of the sentence in almost every "Do you like sth/doing sth" question

Comment: Ask your tutor what he thinks the correct thing to say is. I suspect he may be hung up on the difference between "swimming" and "to swim", but either of those are acceptable.

Comment: I don't see anything ungrammatical about it. It wouldn't be polite to answer a question with a simple "Yes" or "No", so you naturally go on to say _why_ you do or don't like it. But if your teacher says you will be marked down for it, you'll have to accept his advice.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you, I asked to tutor again for an explanation, I'm sharing the links he shared with me which don't contain any explanation. There are many tutors working with British Council, I can honestly say some of them are horrible at their jobs. So before accepting their advices, I usually do a research. The first link is https://www.lawlessenglish.com/learn-english/grammar/questions-yes-no/   and the other one is  https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/questions-and-negatives

Comment: If your tutor is not a native speaker, perhaps he is confused by this: it would be wrong to answer such a question with "Yes, I like" _on its own_ - we say "Yes, I  do) - but there's nothing wrong with "Yes, I like it because I enjoy being in the water" or whatever.